# JAXB cannot get the attached file from soap (WSDL) service

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, jaxb, wsdl

I need to call a SOAP service that returns an attachment.

The XSD that defines the "attached" data is

```
<xs:complexType name="transferableFileData">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:transferableFile">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="fileData" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I am using this plugin in the pom.xml file to generate classes from the WSDL and XSD files

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.15.1</version>
</plugin>
```

The autogenerated class is this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "transferableFileData", propOrder = {
    "fileData"
})
public class TransferableFileData
    extends TransferableFile
{

    protected byte[] fileData;

    
    public byte[] getFileData() {
        return fileData;
    }

   
    public void setFileData(byte[] value) {
        this.fileData = value;
    }

}
```

The response is this one from the server:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Server-Timing: ak_p; desc="1705942361025_1611673733_335963847_52691_3577_46_71_-";dur=1
Server-Timing: origin; dur=520
Server-Timing: edge; dur=7
Server-Timing: cdn-cache; desc=MISS
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: LtpaToken2=Jss03JN+gXMYTd; Path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Mon
Expires: 22 Jan 2024 16:52:41 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 2912
Content-Language: en-US
Date: Mon
Date: 22 Jan 2024 16:52:41 GMT
Content-Type: Multipart/Related; boundary="----=_Part_11_2001319686.1705942360849"; type="application/xop+xml"; start-info="text/xml"
SOAPAction: ""
Accept: text/xml
------=_Part_11_2001319686.1705942360849
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.f4ee8e08bed2d62c7571a5433a8dea327c0877600e72a88b@apache.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns2:downloadPendingFileResponse xmlns:ns2="http://iris.somewhere.cp,/web_services/external/downloadFile" xmlns:ns3="http://iris.somewhere.com/web_services/external/uploadFile"><downloadPendingFileResult><fileExchangeNo>1174649</fileExchangeNo><fileName>TEST00001_2024-01-22-18.46.08.00000_APA.zip</fileName><fileData><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:05ee8e08bed2d62c7571a5433a8dea327c0877600e72a88b@apache.org"/></fileData></downloadPendingFileResult></ns2:downloadPendingFileResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
------=_Part_11_2001319686.1705942360849
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <05ee8e08bed2d62c7571a5433a8dea327c0877600e72a88b@apache.org>

�������f��G��v�+p�,����
��K�ɁZt �K�>b�La���^m��_э���1$�t�dqV�A;�ف� F�K��   ��ކO�X![
```

My Java code goes like this:

```
if (response instanceof JAXBElement) {

                DownloadPendingFileResponse downloadPendingFileResponse = ((JAXBElement<DownloadPendingFileResponse>) response).getValue();
                if(downloadPendingFileResponse == null) {
```

and later

```
final TransferableFileData transferableData = response.getDownloadPendingFileResult();
...
byte[] bytes = transferableData.getFileData();

log.info("length {}", bytes.length);
```

However the length is always zero. It seems that I cannot get the file properly.

What I noticed is that the WSDL defines the fileData element as base64Binary and the POJO has them as byte[]. It seems that the data stream isn't unmarhsaled. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: BASE64 encoding/decoding will be conveniently handled by the JAXB framework for you. In your response the fileData element isn't BASE64 encoded data but a XOP info set which points to the second body part. I don't think how to convince the SOAP framework to deal with this.

Comment: what is a XOP info set?

Comment: XOP aka XML-binary Optimized Packaging is a mechanism where binary data isn't included as encoded data (either BASE64 or CDATA) node directly in your XML document but as binary data in a separate part of a multipart HTTP message. To let the parser know where this data can be found an XOP info set is used.

Comment: The WSDL has base64Binary type, the POJO just byte[]. Why the auto generated class does not contain an annotation in order the field to be unmarhaled as base?

Comment: Not related to question but I'd recommend following this [migration guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Tools-Migration-Guide) to get latest version of the plugin (according your JAXB-api version)

Comment: It is always a good idea to check if a newer version offers something. Unfortunately, the protected byte[] fileData is still there, without any guide for the unmarhaling. I believe that I have somehow to instruct the JAXB to get the fileData field as base64 in order to download the attachment. Still no clue, how to do it.

Comment: How did you get the XSD ?

Comment: @Grafana Next: The byte array is for convenience and safety. You don't want to care about how data is transported. Furthermore BASE64 encoded data is normally represented by a String in Java. Imagine if the property accepts a String! You can't be sure whether this is really BASE64 encoded data or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the exact same XSD on a WSDL service

```xml
<complexType name="myType">
    <sequence>
...
        <element name="myFile" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
...
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

This get generated as by the `org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin` :

```java
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected byte[] myFile;
```

But in order to do the unmarshalling, I had to set a XSLT to `jaxws:feature` spring client in order to tell CXF to understand the `href` in the response (content of file `transform.xsl` as below) :

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >

    <xsl:key name="multiref-by-id" match="multiRef" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(@href, '#')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |
             key('multiref-by-id', substring-after(@href, '#'))/@* |
            key('multiref-by-id', substring-after(@href, '#'))/node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@href[starts-with(., '#')] | multiRef[@id] | @soapenc:root"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the bean defined in XML Spring Config :

```
    <bean id="xsltFeature" class="org.apache.cxf.feature.transform.XSLTFeature">
        <property name="inXSLTPath" value="transform.xsl" />
        <property name="outXSLTPath" value="transform.xsl" />
    </bean>

    <jaxws:client id="myService" serviceClass="my.web.Service" address="myurl">
        <jaxws:features>
            <ref bean="xsltFeature" />
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:client>
```

By doing so, I'm able to read the content of the attached file by the getter of `myFile` in Java without additional config.

I think you can adapt this in order to make it work in your own application context.